# ms access can't edit field because I must delete relationships but there are no relationships to delete

Tags: ms-access, relationship, edit

I have built a database on multiple tables.  One of these tables has a field (Initials) that was originally defined to have 50 characters.  After building the entire thing I realize I would have liked that field to be limited to 3 characters.  I tried to change this, but it tells me that I have to delete one or more relationships.  So, I open up the relationship window and delete the one relationship that is attached to this field, expecting that I should be able to go back and change the character limit then go back and add the relationship again.  So, as of now there are ABSOLUTELY NO relationships touching Initials in the relationships window.  I go back to change the char limit and it gives me the same error.  I can't even delete Initials and recreate it because of the same error.  I went through my entire project and took that field out wherever it appeared.  Still, same error. Any ideas?

Comment: figured it out.  apparently when you display a field in a report it does not show up in the relationships window.  I deleted it from the report, edited the char limit, then put it back in the project.  of course, right when i resort to the forum i figure it out.  thanks to those who helped

Comment: You can post that as an answer (and even accept it after two days). The comment up-votes you got could have been real up-votes already.

Comment: Would that have been a lookup field?

Comment: Two things for others to keep in mind: 1. in the relationships window, you need to choose SHOW ALL on the RELATIONSHIPS menu. 2. to delete an existing relationship, you can't just delete the table -- that just changes the view -- you have to right click the relationship line itself and choose DELETE.

Comment: Tony, Im not really sure what you mean by lookup field.  I had a report that displayed each of the columns from some query that accessed that table.  The column i was attempting to edit was included in that.  it was a very basic report.  
also, thanks for the tip, tomalak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Matt,

> apparently when you display a field in a report it does not show up in the relationships >window. I deleted it from the report, edited the char limit, then put it back in the >project. of course, right when i resort to the forum i figure it out. thanks to those who >helped